# When knitting RMarkdown to HTML with RStudio, is it possible to view directly in browser, instead than previewing in a window?

Tags: html, rstudio, r-markdown

I often with RMarkdown documents which are heavy on math, such as for example:

````
---
title: "Just a test"
author: "Yours Truly"
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'
output:
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo  = FALSE,
               cache = TRUE,
               out.width = "75%", 
               fig.align = "center")
```

## Classical multiple linear regression
A common question in Data Science/Statistics is: how does a certain quantity $y$ depend on other quantities $x_1,\dots,x_p$? Generally, we are interested in $p(y|\mathbf{x})$, the conditional distribution of $y$ given $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_p)$. The simplest and perhaps most widely used model for $p(y|\mathbf{x})$ assumes that, given $\mathbf{x}$, $y$ is normally distributed, with a constant variance $\sigma^2$ and and mean which is a linear function of a parameter vector $\boldsymbol{\beta}=(\beta_0,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_k)$

$$\mathbb{E[y|\mathbf{x}]}=\boldsymbol{\beta}^T\cdot(1,\mathbf{x})=\beta_0+\sum_{j=1}^p\beta_jxj$$
````

When I knit to HTML, RStudio will preview this to a window. To see the HTML in a browser I click on "View in browser":

[image]

Isn't there a way to directly view the HTML in a browser after knitting?

Comment: In my opinion it is possible to choose between "viewer pane", "window" and "none" in Tools -> Global options -> R Markdown -> Show output preview in.

Comment: @J_F yes, I know about that menu, but it doesn't include a "view in Browser" option. I was hoping there would be a way, maybe editing some config file or such.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to figure out how to do this and haven't found a solution.