# R Markdown workflow/testing

Tags: r, testing, r-markdown, workflow

I often create fairly large dashboards with R Markdown. Every time I create a new output (e.g., a new chunk containing an additional table or chart), I want to check for any display issues. My current workflow for doing this is slow for two reasons:

1. I want to test in the browser, but there doesn't seem to be an option to knit a document directly to the browser, so I have to knit to the default window and then click "Open in Browser" (see also here [When knitting RMarkdown to HTML with RStudio, is it possible to view directly in browser, instead than previewing in a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531112/when-knitting-rmarkdown-to-html-with-rstudio-is-it-possible-to-view-directly-in));
2. I do not know of a way to only knit a subset of chunks. For example, is there a way to knit in "test" mode, whereby only certain marked chunks are knitted?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I’m Rstudio you can have a live reload option and have it preview in the viewer pane, and on the right in the IDE you can execute code chunks 1 by 1 to make sure they run properly

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but what I'm after is (1) the ability to preview directly in the browser (i.e., bypass the viewer pane), and (2) the ability to knit (rather than run in the IDE) only selected chunks (by specifying a parameter in the chunk header, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your workflow questions

1. `rmarkdown::run("filename.Rmd", shiny_args = list(launch.browser = TRUE))`

is what you can use, which uses a shiny argument, which will render your  Rmarkdown file and send it directly to the browser when ran. [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851806/rmarkdownrun-directly-displayed-in-the-web-browser)

2. in your chunks, you want the `eval=FALSE`/`eval=TRUE` which tells R to evaluate the chunk or not. You can also use `echo=FALSE` to hide code in the chunk from displaying. Rstudio has added a GUI option to easily select these options with a click of a mouse

[image]

Where only the selected chunk I chose to knit, was actually knitted(1 plot instead of 2.

[image]